# Powerapps navigate to another screen when clicking the underlined words inside the htmltext control value

Tags: function, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a form in powerapps with htmltext control. im pulling the value from a sharepoint list multiline rich text column and the content values has some colored fonts, bold and some has web links that's why im using the htmltext control instead of the normal datacard.

what im to trying achieve is, when i clicked on a word inside the HTML TEXT control value it will navigate to another screen. not opening a web link. i want to navigate to another screen on the app itself.

[image: HTML TEXT CONTROL]

I tried this function If(Find( HtmlTxt_ProSgmnt_Process.HtmlText,"OPS 2.05 Processing Refill Orders") >0, Navigate(Screen2)) that i found in google and expecting to navigate into another screen when clicked the underlined word but no success

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly achieve that using a single HTML Text control. HTML links in HTML Text controls will always open a weblink.

Since you are dealing with a numbered list, how about you create a vertical container with several HTML Text controls that have pseudo-links to invite user interaction? In this scenario you could rely on the control's OnSelect event to navigate to another screen.